# CSS Label, Checkboxs, and Inputform Lineup

Tags: html, css, forms

What would be a proper css method to make the following so it is the same with the exception that the text input fields vertically line up along their left side?

[image]

So the check boxes will still be right up against the input fields and in between the label and input fields, but the input fields still all light up.

Current HTML:

```
<p><label for="search_uri">Uri:</label><input id="search_uri" type="text" name="Uri" /></p>
<p><label for="search_server">Server:</label><input type="checkbox" name="server_like" /><input id="search_server" type="text" name="Server" /></p>
<p><label for="search_host">Host:</label><input id="search_host" type="text" name="Host" /></p>
```

Current CSS:

```
label {
        font-size: 90%;
        float:left;
        width: 15em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a negative margin?

```
.checkbox {margin-left: -16px;}
```

Depending on the rest of your setup might require a bit of tweaking for cross-browser pixel-perfectness.

I would personally probably also just float both the labels and the inputs and get rid of the `<p>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
            font-size: 90%;
            width: 15em;
            clear:left;
        }

        label, input {
            float:left;
        }

        input[type=checkbox]
        /* use .checkbox and add 'class="checkbox"' if you want to support IE6*/
        {
            margin-left: -2em;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="search_uri">Uri:</label>
        <input id="search_uri" type="text" name="Uri" />

        <label for="search_server">Server:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="server_like" />
        <input id="search_server" type="text" name="Server" />

        <label for="search_host">Host:</label>
        <input id="search_host" type="text" name="Host" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this;

```
<div class="label">Uri:</div><div class="field"><input type="text" /></div>
```

Then give the div with the class 'label' an default width and float them next to eachother.

EDIT: Saw you changed your post;

```
<label for="search_uri">Uri:</label>
<input id="search_uri" type="text" name="Uri" />
```

Your css could be something like

```
label
{
    width: 150px;
    float:left;
    clear:both; /*Clear the previous row with label and field, not sure if this is needed*/
}
input
{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Where would the checkbox go in this example?

Comment: @kyle you can put it in the 'div.field' if you want to, or you could create a 'row' above or below the field, leave the label blank and put the checkbox in the field div. Depends a bit on your intended usage

Comment: Why add a div and not just target the elements themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

HTML Markup:

```
<form><fieldset>
<legend>Login Details</legend>
<label>Your Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="32" />
<label>Your Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />
</fieldset>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create Account" /></form>
```

Css Markup:

```
fieldset {padding: 10px 0;}
legend {font-weight: bold; padding: 0 0 3px 0; color: #f00;}
input {padding: 2px; border-radius: 3px; width: 130px; float: left; margin: 0 0 5px 0;}
label {float: left; width: 150px; text-align: right; margin: 1px 3px 0 0;}
#submit {width: auto; margin: 0 0 0 153px;}
```

Then add a width to your form, depending on the input sizes, with your checkbox, just float it in between and use margins.

Comment: But won't some of these carefully crafted pixel values stop working if the user have larger / smaller font, or  different size of control widgets (e.g. the checkbox)?

Comment: Then set the values to em for all text related css. And for the checkbox the margin can still be displayed in px as it position will want to be fixed relative to where it floats next to the chosen input field.

Answer (score -1):

If your form is small, you can just use a `<table>`.

Comment: It is so much easier with css.

Comment: I always learned not to use tables for styling. Only for data represenations.

Comment: @basic: it depends; the original poster did ask how to do this with tableless CSS, while with tables, it's straightforward. And tables are perfectly CSS-able, too. Also, Press Ctrl+U (or otherwise invoke View Source) right here.

Comment: @Potherca: don't hold yourself. But an explanation why a small 3x3 table is bad, and which kind of layout would be semantically superiour _and_ easy to create and support would be very welcome. I'm always eager to learn.

Comment: Css is always semantically superior when it comes to tables in forms, as it seperates content from display, using tables adds extra markup to your html file which isn't needed, labels would not be semantically directly next to input fields as they would have to be in different columns of the row, only minor things, but semantically, css is better than tables in forms, tables are for tables, labels input fieldset and legend are for forms, period.

Comment: @9000 Added code example to my answer, hope it's clear enough.